# Enable "Connect to office" in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, office-integration, office

I need to enable "Connect to Office" in our SharePoint 2010 standard and can't find where to do this, can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By "Connect to Office" I'm guessing you mean "Connect to Outlook"?

To do this you need to:

- Navigate to the library or list that you would like to connect to.
- In the Ribbon, click the Library/List tab
- Click the Connect to Outlook button in the middle of the Ribbon

Comment: Thanks, but no there is an option beside the connect to outlook named connect to office and the button is disabled (greyed out) i was wondering if anyone knew how to enable it.

Comment: You need to have SharePoint Support installed for Office 2010...Try to Modify the installation through Control Panel -> Programs -> Modify, and Add the SharePoint Support Feature.